# Select only records which does not a have any 'D' as status

Tags: sql

I need to select only those transaction which does not have any 'D' as status.

sample data:

```
T_ID | DATE       | STATUS
101  | 2019-01-01 | N
101  | 2019-01-02 | U
101  | 2019-01-01 | D
102  | 2019-01-01 | N
```

Expected:

```
T_ID | DATE       | STATUS
102  | 2019-01-01 | N
```

Since the T_ID 101 has a 'D' status, i don't want to have the T_ID '101' that in my output.

Comment: Have you considered the [where clause](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_where.asp)?

Answer (score 2):

Use below query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE T_ID NOT IN (
   SELECT T_ID FROM table_name WHERE status = 'D'
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

If your version of SQL supports analytic functions, we may try using `COUNT` here to filter:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT T_ID, DATE, STATUS,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'D' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY T_ID) AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT T_ID, DATE, STATUS
FROM cte
WHERE cnt = 0;
```

[image]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can also write query below:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE T_ID in (SELECT T_ID FROM table_name WHERE status = 'D')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the transaction id, then aggregation does what you want:

```
select t_id
from t
group by t_id
having sum(case when t.status = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where t_id = t.t_id and status = 'D'
)
```